# Solidity - Add Total Supply

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I'm learning solidity on [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/)
I'm also referencing this [open source](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) api for token creation.

Right [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L92) they provide a `_totalSupply()` function that I'd like to wire to my smart contract so it shows the total amount of tokens why I deploy it.

What am doing wrong here?

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Foobar is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20("Foobar", "FOO") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
       // add totalSupply here
        _totalSupply(uint256 5000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenZeppelin ERC20 `_totalSupply` is a private property, which means you can't access it from a derived contract (in your case `Foobar`).

- [GitHub link](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L38) to the property definition
- [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) on visibility modifiers

Also your syntax is incorrect. If the property were at least `internal`, you could set its value as

```
_totalSupply = 5000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
```

or in a more readable way

```
_totalSupply = 5 * 1e39;
```

---

If you want to change its visibility, you'll need to copy the (parent) `ERC20` contract to your IDE and change the import statement to reflect the new (local) location. Then you'll be able to update the property visibility in your local copy of the contract.

Mind that the OpenZeppelin `ERC20` contains relative import paths (e.g. `import "./IERC20.sol";`). You'll need to rewrite these in your local copy as well, so that they point back to the GitHub locations. Otherwise, the compiler would be trying to import non-existing local files.

Comment: thank you @Petr Hejda - that explains why I can't compile my code on BSC so it's visible under their contract tab. It does not recognize the imports.

Answer (score 2):

OpenZeppelin contracts automatically update `totalSupply` when you `mint` or `burn` tokens. They also automatically expose this as a variable you can read. You do not need, and you should not and you cannot set `totalSupply` by hand, because then the  number of distributed tokens would not match the total supply.

Comment: Thank you - So by that definition I only need my `mint` function above and everything else (total supply) would happen under the hood?

Comment: For the verification, I also suggest reading the source code of contracts you inherit.